# Changing colors for multiple lists

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">

<p><span style="color: #ffffff;">Through the program, you will use these disciplines which include:</span></p>
<ul><li>Neuroscience</li>
<li>Business management</li>
<li>Philosophy</li>
</ul>

<!-- Further down the page I have:  -->
<ul><li>Increase your circle of influence</li>
<li>Inspire growth through authenticity</li>
<!-- However the background here is White and it works well with the text colour of dark blue -->
```

I have a website which has multiple colors as the background and I am putting text on the page.
I'm using "< spans color=#123456/ffffff >" for the text but with the bullet points it's not working correctly.

Ideally I want to add a CSS entry to say UL1 color = black and UL2 color = white. with the bullet points and text as either Black/White.

Currently if I use the span setting I can see the text as black/white but the bullet point is black. With a black background, you can't see the bullet point.

An example is:

- Bullet Point 1
- Bullet point 2

with a second list further down the page of:

- White bullet point on black background
- Second White bullet point on black background

Is this possible to do?

Thanks in Advance.

Pher.

Comment: Can you share the source you have, as well as the desired result?

Comment: Source appears like this:  


<ul color: #ffffff>  

  <li>Neuroscience</li>  

  <li>Business management</li>    

and the second list is     

<ul>    
  <li>Increase your circle of influence</li>    

  <li>Inspire growth through authenticity</li>    


What I want is for the top list to show with #09203E as the background and White as the text, including the bullet point.  

and the bottom as with white as the background and #09203E as the text color.

Comment: and where is the `<span>`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code, preferably as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar)

Comment: I had the <span style="color: #ffffff;"> Neuroscience</span> and it changed the text to white, however the bullet point was still dark blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code sample can help you to change color of buttet points as well text of list

```css
.home {
        color: red;
      }
      .products {
        color: blue;
      } 
      .about {
        color: yellow;
      }
      .contact{
      color: green;
      }
       .bullet {
        color: red;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
 
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="bullet">
      <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="products" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="about" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="dropdownLink"><a href="">&#9776;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's awesome Radha. Does it need to be a navlink class?
if I change the code to  <li class="product"> Products </a> will that go through as blue?
I appreciate your fast response and help.

Comment: no you don't need to use navlink, I am using that for some other development work so you can ignore navlink as of now.
I have updated code snapshot to help you better